# Using NASA Horizons with Celestrak Socrates's TLE CDMs?

Tags: nasa, jpl-horizons, ephemeris, ssa

Has anyone succeeded with getting a list of Collision Data Messages (CDMs) from nice sites like Celestrak in order to feed them into NASA Horizon's ephemeris computation service. These would include LEO up to GEO probability of collision numbers

Comment: The CDM data available from https://celestrak.org/SOCRATES assumes every covariance is 100-300-100 m RIC, and uses TLEs for state vectors.  https://www.space-track.org/#/conjunctions reports exclusion volumes, but the first 50 I checked all used 5 m spheres for both objects.  Unless you've got access to VCMs, I don't think the CDMs I could find are going to help.

Comment: I can understand why the COV is excluded, a competitor could determine the sensor tracking error.  Can the competitor reverse-engineer the ephemerides generated from the VCM?

Comment: At the last time I was able to get VCMs, they were considered individually U//FOUO, but a complete set was considered Secret by compilation, due to worries about what it might reveal about the measurement systems, so they were only distributed on Siprnet, which made it really annoying to use them in an unclassified setting.

Comment: I imagine ephemerides generated from an TLE is quite 'rough' and I believe this is what the NASA Horizon site does.  What if a site offered that same kind of service for LEO TLE but they have the 'backroom' VCM so TCA can be calculated when needed for maneuver reasons.  You, as the user can't look at the VCM data, on use the service.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are planing, but space-track.org is basically offering this service: they have the ephemeris from 18/19 SDS, provide CDMs and you can sent your planned manoeuvre to check befor executing